# Automatic .cpp file creation for emacs

Tags: c++, emacs

I'm looking for a plugin for emacs, that  would, after calling command from .hpp file, automatically create corresponding .cpp file, fill it with function declarations.

Example:

I've created file Animal.hpp

```
//...#ifndefs
class Animal
{
   std::string name;
   int vel;
public:
   Animal();
   Animal(const std::string& nam, int v);
   ~Animal() = default;

   void Run();
   std::string& MyName();
};
```

This .hpp, after calling function, would be parsed and emacs would create this file for me:

Animal.cpp

```
#include "Animal.hpp"
Animal::Animal()
{

}

Animal::Animal(const std::string& nam, int v)
{

}

void Animal::Run()
{

}

std::string& Animal::MyName()
{

}
```

Waiting for me to code :)

Is there anything like that?

Comment: I don't know of any, but you could make one if Google doesn't turn anything up?

Comment: I would recommend to look to CEDET's SRecode package - it doesn't have the ready to use code, but you can use it to generate necessary parts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I've found out that there's a thing called lisp:member-functions.el.
Here's the link: [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExpandMemberFunctions)
It does just what I wanted.